# Replacing String in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have Database table and I am using SQL Server 2008.

The table contins some columns and in one column the variable type is "String." The column looks like as follows:

```
ColumnA

12301 01

12342 02

12501 01

43201 02

56401 03

56766 01

53478 01

54601 04
```

There is a white space in between the first 5 digits and last two digits. I want to replace last two digits to `09` if last two digits in the string are `01`.

Comment: Three functions can do this: REPLACE(), SUBSTRING() and IF(). You should look them up, combining them is a fairly simple exercise.

Comment: Are you unable to separate it into two columns to avoid the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table
  SET ColumnName = LEFT(ColumName, 6) + '09'
Where ColumnName LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] 01'
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `LIKE` operator to find all rows that end in a [space] + 01 and then use the `REPLACE` method to replace 01 with 09

```
UPDATE  [YourTable]
SET     ColumnA = REPLACE(ColumnA, ' 01', ' 09')
WHERE   ColumnA LIKE '% 01'
```

You can test the query here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/116590/

**WARNING:**

Never run updates statements against your production data without first testing them in a development environment - especially if you didn't write the SQL!

Comment: @sll, Thanks on both accounts! I didn't see anything that said I couldn't use DataExplorer for such things, so I've been going with it :)

Comment: I don't like those WARNING comments. Let's assume that people are responsible for the work they do.

Comment: @Frans, I think a down-vote because you don't like my warning is inappropriate and a matter of opinion. This is a valid warning and a correct answer.

Comment: (tried to) Removed the downvote. But why always these warnings? People ask questions and we answer them. It's their responsibility to use the answers in a profesional way. It's not your warning that worries me. What worries me is that every answer will end with WARNING!

Comment: edit your question and I can upvote again. What a stupid design :)

Answer (score 1):

Since column values always has single space before last two characters you can leverage this to simplify replacement logic, so you do not need any complex checks:

```
UPDATE Table
SET ColumnA = REPLACE (ColumnA, ' 01', '09')
WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%' + ' 01'
```